# How do I edit "services" on Ubuntu 14.04 on Digital Ocean?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Digital Ocean's docs ask me to write inputs like `service gunicorn restart` or `service nginx restart`.

What is the `service` package? How can I figure out what it is so that I can edit how it works (e.g., change paths of services so their .conf files can be in source control). I'm using an automated Django droplet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See at `/etc/init.d` directory.

`service nginx restart` --> `/etc/init.d/nginx`